# Python - Copying only new files into another directory

Tags: python, copying

I'm trying to copy files from one directory into another ONLY if those files don't already exist.

So if I have directory A with files "1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt" and  directory B with files "1.txt, 2.txt", I want to only copy "3.txt" into directory B without rewriting the other files.

I'm a Python beginner and I've spent hours on this and have done plenty of research but I just can't seem to find the answer! Help!

Thanks

Comment: Create a for loop in the original directory and then use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-using-python to determine if the file already exists. If it doesn't copy the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll help you out, and lead you to the answer (but I won't just outright give it to you!).

So, first things first, most basic file editing functions are in the `os` module, so let's import that at the top of our script:

```
import os
```

Now let's see how we check if a file exists. [A little research shows the `os.path` module has a function called `exists` which checks if a file exists!] So now we're set, but we have to figure out how to get all the files in directory A. It looks like the `os` module works for this too, with the `listdir` function. If we have a directory called "directoryone", we could get all the files / directories in it (and then put them in a list) with this:

```
[file for file in os.listdir("directoryone")]
```

But we only want to get files, so we have to add an `if` statement to narrow down our list:

```
[file for file in os.listdir("directoryone") if os.path.isfile(os.path.join("directoryone", f))]
```

So now we have a statement which gets all the files in a directory, and we have a way to check if a file exists. The last thing we need to do is figure out how to copy files. We have to import the `shutil` model for this:

```
import shutil
```

And then we can use the `shutil.copy` function as so:

```
shutil.copy(srcfile, dstdir)
```

So we'd end up with this code:

```
import os, shutil

directorya = "exampledir"
directoryb = "exampledir2"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(directorya) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directorya, file))]
for file in files:
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(directoryb, file)):
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(directorya, file), directoryb)
```

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown. Solved my problem and taught me the method. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 2):

Get the list of files in both directory and u will get using [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir)

```
>>> a_files = ['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt']
>>> b_files = ['1.txt', '2.txt']
```

Take a difference of both list.

```
>>> set(a_files) - set(b_files)
set(['3.txt'])
```

U will get only `3.txt` copy this file to folder `B`

Comment: Just `difference`. `symmetric_difference` will cause problems if there are any extra files in `b_files`. Eg. `set(a_files).difference(b_files)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy only files with the extension *.txt you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import glob
import os
import shutil
dira = 'path-to-dira'
dirb = 'path-to-dirb'

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(dira,'*.txt')):
   print os.path.join(dirb,os.path.basename(filename))
   if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirb,os.path.basename(filename))):
       shutil.copy(filename,dirb)
```

If you want all files replace `'*.txt'` with `'*'`

Comment: Thanks for the "*.txt" addition, great to know!

Answer (score 0):

```
import shutil
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

DIR_A = "<Complete path to A directory>"
DIR_B = "<Complete path to B directory>"

onlyfiles_A = [ f for f in listdir(DIR_A) if isfile(join(DIR_A,f)) ]
onlyfiles_B = [ f for f in listdir(DIR_B) if isfile(join(DIR_B,f)) ]

for f_a in onlyfiles_A:
    if not f_a in onlyfiles_B:
        src = DIR_A+"/"+f_a
        shutil.copy(src, DIR_B)
```

For more information browse through this link:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do the next:

```
import glob
import shutil

src = "/opt/"
dst = "/opt/something/"

files_src = set(glob.glob(src+"*.txt"))
files_dst = set(glob.glob(dst+"*.txt"))

other_files = files_src-files_dst
for _file in other_files:
    shutil.copy(src+_file, dst)
```